# Spacing problems when using align equation

Tags: spacing, align, gap

I am writing a report, and when I use in my subsection the `\begin{align}`, there is a great gap created between the subsection title and the first paragraph, when I remove it, the gap is removed.

[image]

So I think the problem lies in using it, how can I fix this ?

```
% documentclass options:
% ngerman is needed for hyphenation if the thesis contains parts written in German
% BCOR is binding correction
% if you'd rather have a one sided thesis, add `onside' to the documentclass
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, BCOR=10mm, english, ngerman]{scrbook}

% include all packages and define commands in setup.tex
\input{setup}

    \begin{document}
        \pagestyle{empty} % no header and no page number
        % disable hyper links to remove warning "destination with same identifier"
        % this means within this section nothing can be referenced with a hyperlink
        \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
        \include{chapters/0_0-titlepage}
        \pagestyle{plain} % remove chapter name from top, page number at the bottom
        \frontmatter  % roman page numbers
        \include{chapters/0_1-declaration}
        \include{chapters/0_2-acknowledgments}
        \include{chapters/0_3-abstract}
        \renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents
        \listoffigures
        \listoftables
        \listofalgorithms
        \hypersetup{pageanchor=true}  % re-enable hyperlinking

        \mainmatter  % Arabic page numbers
        \include{chapters/1-introduction}
        \include{chapters/2-background}
        \include{chapters/3-approach}
        \include{chapters/4-implementation}
        \include{chapters/5-Results}
        \include{chapters/6-conclusions}

        %\include{chapters/2-relatedwork}
        % bibliography is not in the table of contents per default, add it manually
        \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
        \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
        \bibliography{bib/topic1}
        \newpage
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \mbox{}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post the code of a complete document (starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` that shows your problem when typeset. Without it we have no idea which of your specific settings causes this phenomenon. Use the `edit` button at the bottom left of your question to add the code.

Comment: I guess that you problem is caused by a figure or a table environment somewhere else in your document.  Latex tries to keep [floating](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) environments in a nice place, and sometimes this leads to horrible vertical white space else where.  The usual advice is not to worry about such breaks until you have got a more or less complete document written.

Comment: @gernot I added it

Comment: Please make the mwe standalone, you're including a lot of stuff we do not have access to. Please reduce your example to something that can be copied and tested as is.

Comment: @daleif sorry I don't understand, what is mwe standalone ? I am not expert in LaTeX

Comment: We don't have any of the files you input by `\input`, `\include` or `\bibliography ` (the last one is irrelevant in this case). So your example is useless to us, we cannot test your code. Make something that in it self does not include files we do not have access to (that is what "standalone" means). As we cannot test your code, we cannot help further.

Comment: Unexpected gaps are generally the result of LaTeX having to stretch text to fit the page.  A simple solution is to throw in a \vfill where you want the gap to appear, or use \raggedbottom.  In this case you might want to put \displaybreak in the;middle of the math, or \allowdisplaybreaks in the preamble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These commands let the gap disappear

```
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{7pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{7pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{7pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{7pt}
```

Comment: That is not a good solution. But your choice, you still haven't provided any code that shows the problem.

Comment: `\begin{align*}
D_{KL}(P||Q) &= H(P,Q) - H(X) \\
&= \sum_{x\in X} p(x).(\log p(x) - \log q(x)) \\
&= \sum_{x\in X} p(x)\log p(x) - \sum_{x\in X} p(x)\log q(x)
\end{align*}` This is the equation that is causing the problem

Comment: How is that even related to your posted image. Again, we need a full minimal example that shows the problem. This math sniplet has no issues. (though I'm not sure what you mean by `P||Q`, that looks strange)